# CSS behaviour not the same for HTML and JSF

Tags: html, css, jsf, xhtml, jsf-1.2

I have a few html pages with css files and it works perfectly when opened in chrome. If I copy the exact content into JSF (xhtml) pages without converting the html components to jsf components (h:inputs etc.) the styling behaviour is not the same. 99% of the components appear the same as with the html files, but some of them have styling issues. I have noticed that a user agent stylesheet rule was added on one of the components.

Should the behaviour for JSF (xhtml) pages with HTML content be same as normal HTML files with regards to styling and css?

I am using JSF 1.2 with IceFaces 1.8.2 and NetBeans 6.8

Comment: I think that you have css loaded for IceFaces... look in the header of the result page.

Comment: Indeed, UI-oriented JSF component libraries like PrimeFaces, RichFaces and ICEfaces usually ship with their own default stylesheets. Just check it in the webbrowser's builtin webdeveloper toolset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. @BalusC I really appreciate your time. There are no additional stylesheets from ICEfaces. Only the stylesheets that I am importing. The HTML template that I am using can be found in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234927/jsf-2-ajax-and-custom-jquery-components).